# Two way split in Classification and Regression Trees (CART)

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, classification, cart

If I've multiple attributes of a variable say weather (Windy, Cloudy, Overcast). After calculating the Gini index of each value. I've to apply CART algorithm, as it works on binary split. which pair of combination of values would i need to go for (with less or high Gini ) ?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refere to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning#Gini_impurity

> Gini impurity is a measure of how often a randomly chosen element from
>   the set would be incorrectly labeled if it was randomly labeled
>   according to the distribution of labels in the subset. ... It reaches its minimum (zero) when all cases in the node fall into a single target category.

At each split, the CART algorithm needs to choose the attributes that gives the highest *information gain* or least *gini impurity*. Hence you should choose the split that gives less gini impurity, i.e., 0.167.